# Non transparent text box and picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

How can i create non transparent text box in a specific position so that when i put the textbox the back-ground becomes invisible ? Also how can i overlay pictures on text so that text becomes invisible when i put the figure. Please see the pictures below to see what i am trying to achieve.

I have tried with tikzpicture but in vain.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,opacity=1]
\node[anchor=north west, %anchor is upper left corner of the graphic
xshift=0.4cm, %shifting around
yshift=-6.5cm] 
at (current page.north west) %left upper corner of the page
{\includegraphics[page=8]{figures.pdf}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, add a MWE!

Comment: @Dib You must add the `remember picture` option  (that requires two compilations).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: Use \only<1> on the "background" and \only<2> on the "foreground".